# dataframe内の数値から文字列に変換する方法

Tags: python, pandas

```
  file_name  expression
0   test_0000.jpg   1
1   test_0001.jpg   0
2   test_0002.jpg   0
3   test_0003.jpg   0
4   test_0004.jpg   2
... ... ...
307  test_0307.jpg  1
308  test_0308.jpg  0
309  test_0309.jpg  1
310  test_0310.jpg  3
311 test_0311.jpg   1
```

このdataframeの `expression` 行の数値を

`0`⇒`neutral`
`1`⇒`happy`
`2`⇒`sad`
`3`⇒`angry`
に変換したく、下記のコードを実装させたのですが

```py
Submit['expression'].replace({'0':'neutral', '1':'happy', '2':'sad', '3':'angry'})
```

このエラーが発生してしまいました。

```
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=uint8)' and 'str'
```

以下の事を試しましたが、

1. replace時にstrに変換

```py
Submit['expression'].replace(str.maketrans({'0':'neutral', '1':'happy', '2':'sad', '3':'angry'}))
```

2. dataframe作成時に数値の行を文字列に変換

```py
Submit1 = Submit['expression'].astype(str)
```

エラーになってしまい変換することが出来ませんでした。

このエラーに対してのアドバイスを頂けたら幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 参考までに、[BUG: df.replace with numeric values and str to_replace by jbrockmendel · Pull Request #36093 · pandas-dev/pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/36093/commits/8c8b36fcb79998754cdf13bc9abddcfd711f1944) が原因かと思われます(2020/9/5 に master branch にマージ済み)

Answer (score 1):

変換用辞書を数値のキーにする方法と, 文字列のまま使用する方法を行いました
どちらも利用可能です

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
  ['test_0000.jpg', 1],
  ['test_0001.jpg', 0],
  ['test_0002.jpg', 0],
  ['test_0003.jpg', 0],
  ['test_0004.jpg', 2]], columns=['file_name','expression'])

dct_int = {0: 'neutral', 1: 'happy', 2: 'sad', 3: 'angry'}
dct_str = {'0': 'neutral', '1': 'happy', '2': 'sad', '3': 'angry'}

df['exp_name'] = df['expression'].replace(dct_int)
df['exp_name2'] = df['expression'].astype(str).replace(dct_str)
display(df)
```

---

試したこと (1) では `replace` に与える辞書としては不適当で, 変換に失敗するでしょう。
試したこと (2) では, 何が失敗したのか不明です

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
こちらのコードでも実装してみたところ問題なく変換できました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @hideto.tsuzuki 解決済みの場合, 何かマーク付けることができるようです。(そうでないと未解決として残り続けます)
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

dfは下記のDataFrameとする。

```
    file_name   expression
0   test_0000.jpg   1
1   test_0001.jpg   0
2   test_0002.jpg   0
3   test_0003.jpg   0
4   test_0004.jpg   2
5   test_0307.jpg   1
6   test_0308.jpg   0
7   test_0309.jpg   1
8   test_0310.jpg   3
9   test_0311.jpg   1
```

expression列の型を変換してから置換すれば良いでしょう。

```
df['expression'] = df['expression'].astype(str)
df['expression'] = df['expression'].replace({'0':'neutral', '1':'happy', '2':'sad', '3':'angry'})
print(df)
#   file_name   expression
#0  test_0000.jpg   happy
#1  test_0001.jpg   neutral
#2  test_0002.jpg   neutral
#3  test_0003.jpg   neutral
#4  test_0004.jpg   sad
#5  test_0307.jpg   happy
#6  test_0308.jpg   neutral
#7  test_0309.jpg   happy
#8  test_0310.jpg   angry
#9  test_0311.jpg   happy
```

Comment: 的確なコメントありがとうございます。
記載コード通りに行ったら問題なく実装されました。
ありがとうございました。